# Setting up a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question was:
A radioactive element decays at a rate proportional to the mass remaining. Initially the mass is 10mg and after 20 days it is 5mg. Set up a differential equation describing this situation and solve it to find the time taken to reach 1mg.

Can someone please tell me how do I find dy/dt at t=0 because I can't seem to get that from the question although I tried solving it by diving 5 by 20 it get the rate of change per day, but I ended up with t equals to a negative number so there must be something wrong. 
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to find $y'(0)$. It wasn't given and the question didn't ask you to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation that describes the mass of a radioactive element is

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-ky,$$ where $k$ is some constant. If you solve the differential equation then you get that

$$y(t)=y(0)e^{-kt}.$$ Since $y(0)$ it is assumed to be $10$ $\text{mg}$ then it is

$$y(t)=10e^{-kt}.$$

Now, since it is $$5=10e^{-20k}$$ we get that $k=\frac{\ln 2}{20}.$ Thus $y'(0)=-10k=-\ln \sqrt{2}.$

Comment: I have reached this as well, but my problem is that I cant find dy/dx at t=0, the question only gives you at t=20. Can anyone tell me how can I find dy/dx at t=0 so I can find k?

Comment: I have editted my answer to give a complete answer instead of a hint.